# Prove the equation of the result of square projection

Tags: geometry

> Given a square $ABCD$ and a line $g$. The vertices $A', B', C', D'$ is a projection of every vertex $A, B, C, D$ on $g$. Prove that $(A'C') ^2 + (B'D')^2 = 2(AB)^2$

I tried to draw a vertical line, so the projection is not hard to imagine. But, it keeps me confuse what is the projection here means. By the way, could you help me please?

Comment: The projection of a point $P$ onto a line $\ell$ is the point $P'$ on $\ell$ such that the distance between $P$ and $P'$ is minimized. So intuitively, the segment $P'P$ is perpendicular to the line $\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

Let square inscribed in unit circle without losing generality.
$A=(\cosθ,\sinθ),B=(\cos(θ+90°),\sin(θ+90°)),C=(\cos(θ+180°),\sin(θ+180°)),D=(\cos(θ+270°),\sin(θ+270°))$.

$$A'C'^2+B'D'^2=(\cosθ-\cos(θ+180°))^2+(\cos(θ+90°)-\cos(θ+270))^2$$
$=4\cos^2θ+4\sin^2θ=4=2AB^2$